# Remove Files whit name '\'

Tags: linux, bash, file

I make mistake file with this name '' and i do not know how to clear this file
How to remove the file with this name '' ?

```
 rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1555 Sep 15 12:54 '\'
```

Comment: my file name is '\'

Comment: Do you really need an answer in C code for this? Doesn't `remove` work?

Answer (score 3):

You could follow 2 steps to do this.

1- Get the inode number of that specific file by doing `ls -litr Input_file_name`

2- Then use following command to delete it by inode number: (replace `1235` with your actual inode number which you get in your previous step)

```
find . -inum 1235 -exec rm {} \;
```

---

---

***Working example:*** Its a dummy/test example only for understanding purposes.

1- Do `ls -lihtr` to get inode number:

```
total 16K
  1227 -rw-r--r-- 1 singh singh   0 Sep 15 08:05 \\\\
```

2- Now place that in `find` command as follows to delete that specific file:

```
find . -inum 1227 -exec rm {} \;
```

***NOTE:*** As per @JRFerguson's comment, there could be same inode number files/symlinks, so better to give either `.` or complete path in `find` command to make sure it deletes the correct file and add `-xdev` option to above find command too.

Comment: @JRFerguson, sure thank you for information. `find` command I ran has `.` so it will look for the current directory only, I could add warning into my answer now, kindly do let me know any queries please, thanks again for your informative comment.

Comment: I should have said, *To prevent descending into directories on other filesystems...*,  Symbolic links don't matter. The `-xdev` option prevents descent into directories on other filesystems. A classic case would be if you were searching the `/` filesystem. Then, `xdev` would prevent entering mounted directories like `/tmp`, and `/var`. An old habit of mine always adds `-xdev` when dealing with removing files by inode. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ rm \\
```

Works for me (with `bash`). Or, if you have an interactive file manager available (which might be `mc` if all you have is a terminal) just use a point-and-click method. It's the shell's escaping that's causing all the problems here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-quote the filename and escape the backslash in the shell with another backslash

```sh
rm "'\\'"
```

Comment: rm: cannot remove ''\''\'\''': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape both `'` and `\` with `\`.

The following command

```
rm \'\\\'
```

should do the trick.